# Calling VB Script (macro) within PowerPoint using SharePoint

Tags: vba, sharepoint-2007, powerpoint

Is it possible to call macro within a sample powerpoint presentation using SharePoint Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I searched to find out if it would be possible to call a presentation and a macro from a web page.
This is what I found: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683